# Numpy __isub__ changing global variable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, namespaces

I've been struggling with some operations over NumPy arrays and functions in a recent script. I've finally discovered what seems to be the error: NumPy __isub__.

Heres a example:

```py
def test(apocalypse):
    apocalypse = apocalypse - 3
    return apocalypse

def test2(apocalypse):
    apocalypse -= 3
    return apocalypse

foo = np.array([1,2,3])
print(test(foo))
print(foo)

bar = np.array([1,2,3])
print(test2(bar))
print(bar)
```

Which results in:

```
[-2 -1  0]
[1 2 3]
[-2 -1  0]
[-2 -1  0]
```

Was it expected? Should `-=` change a global variable (same for `+=`)? I've tried with int and float instead of NumPy arrays and it worked as I expected.

Comment: Yes, the difference wih `int` and `float` is that these are immutable values.

Comment: `ndarray` is mutable, so `arr -= 3` modifies `arr` itself.  That's normal.  `alist.append(3)` is another example that modifies a mutable object.

Comment: OMG, i didn't check if ```-=``` was mutable. Assignments always create a new reference, but -= is not an assignment, it is more a kind of "mutating method", right?

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer in case anybody needs more details than the [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091031/numpy-isub-changing-global-variable#comment108078954_61091031) and [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091031/numpy-isub-changing-global-variable#comment108078854_61091031) quick and good answers.

I'm supposing we already understand how mutable/immutable objects work. If not, [here we have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/8000701) an answer about it, in a *by reference vs by assignment* context.

The problem I faced was due to the fact that *isub* is an in-place operator and it was used with a mutable object so the original variable passed by assignment to the `test` function has its object changed, having not to do with global variables as I supposed.

Note that as we could see, it's not because you have a mutable object that all operations will change the object in-place though. Example with `id`:

```py
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
print(id(arr))    # prints 139838225358560
arr += 3 
print(arr)        # prints [4 5 6]
print(id(arr))    # prints 139838225358560
arr = arr + 3
print(arr)        # prints [7 8 9]
print(id(arr))    # prints 139838016018832
```

The in-place operator `+=` performs the change of the object `arr` while the assignment `=` creates a new one. The same goes in my question with `apocalypse -= 3` and `apocalypse = apocalypse - 3`, respectively.

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#in-place-operators) has a short and good explanation of in-place operators with a list of them.